# Can I change the default response color in Linux Terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, colors, readability

It would be nice to be able to easily see the conversations I have with my computer in 'call and response' style, so my input lines are in one color, and what is returned shows in a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your `~/.bashrc`

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export PS1="\[$(tput setaf 1)\]\h:\W\\$ "
```

This will enable colour for your terminal and set your prompt to dark red. The CLICOLOR may not be required on some systems, but for some (such as Mac OS X) it is disabled by default.

A useful tool for building your own custom prompt can be found at https://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ps1.html

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the terminal -> Profile ->profile preferences. Here you can play around with colour and visual settings.

EDIT

Sorry I did not quite get problem.
[On this other forum is well explained](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442319/ubuntu-terminal-xfce-making-input-commands-different-font-color-from-output-t)

Comment: In profile preferences I can change the settings for the entire window, I want to know if it's possible to have the input lines in a separate color from the output.

Comment: thanks for the link, it helped me understand the strings Aaron D mentioned above.  Cheers.